# Loading levels with xml in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

In porting my game over to cocos2d, i have level files i would like to use with my game.

My android engine has a xml reader that automatically parses the file.

Does cocos2d have something like this? Or will i need to create my own?

If there is a better way to do this please let me know, as i am new to ios development. Is there a tool we could use for this?

If so, how would you go about parsing and loading the level based on the xml file?

Thank you all for your help

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class

Answer (score 0):

Just like Steffen said.You can use NSXMLParser to parse the xml file.
Or if you work with cocos2d-iphone, you can rewrite your xml file into a plist file, it's very convenient.
Here is a sample code:

```
NSString *configPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourLevelConfig"
ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *configDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:configPath];
```

The node in xml is just like a key in dictionary.Here is a link about [how to write a plist file in objective-c](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/05/30/property-list-tutorial-using-plist-to-store-user-data/).

Or if you work with cocos2d-x, I recommend to use tinyXml2 which is under the "support" directory.

Hope this helps:)